# Android Studio removes details from AppManifest

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a intermediate Java developer starting to look into developing Android apps. I am following the tutorials that Google provides, but I am running into an issue where Android Studio is removing code from the App Manifest. Specifically I am looking at this tutorial: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

When I add these details to the AppManifest, Android studio removes them at compile time:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Without these details, the app crashes because it does not know what the parent activity is.

Comment: Removes them? Does it deletes these lines or shows some errors/red cross marks?  When you clear and rebuild, still the same thing happens?

Comment: It completely removes them as if they were never there. I even tried copy and pasting directly from Google. It does not mark them red or anything, they just disappear.

Comment: Strange. Only issue I can think of is that you are editing the `AndroidManifest` which is present inside `bin` folder and not which is in the main project. That one obviously gets replaced always.

Comment: Another thought: If its happening in other files of the code as well, then it might be that the place where you have your code is write protected. This can happen if you start eclipse from different user than where the code exists.

Comment: Shobhit Puri, you are correct. I was editing the wrong AppManifest.xml file. I did not realize there were two of them. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I can think of is that you are editing the wrong `AndroidManifest` which is present inside `bin` folder and not which is in the main project. That one obviously gets replaced always.

If its happening in other files of the code as well, then it might be that the place where you have your code is write protected. This can happen if you start eclipse from different user than where the code exists.